# Clerics in Mystara - Which divine spheres does each Immortal allow?

Tags: cleric, adnd-2e, religions-and-deities, mystara

Can anyone help me because I can't find any reference to what, or how many Divine Spheres each Immortal allows to their clerics. I own the Karameikos, kingdom of adventure book, and it tells about them but don't specify which spheres they grant. Is there any book that has this information, or do I have to simply decide this as the DM? If so, how many primary and secondary spheres can an Immortal grant to their followers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2nd Edition Red Steel / Savage Coast material provides suggestions for giving clerics different spell lists based on the sphere of their deities.

***Matter.*** Major access to all, animal, elemental earth, plant, and summoning. Minor access to combat, creation, divination, and healing.

***Energy.*** Major access to all, creation, elemental fire, sun, and weather. Minor access to combat, guardian, healing, and summoning.

***Thought.*** Major access to all astral, divination, elemental air, and summoning. Minor access to charm, guardian, healing, and weather.

***Time.*** Major access to all, creation, divination, elemental water, and healing. Minor access to animal, necromantic, plant, and sun.

***Entropy.*** Major access to all, combat, divination, healing (reversed only), and necromantic. Minor access to elemental (reversed only), plant (reversed only), summoning, and weather.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This looks like your converting white wolf Mage into D&D? I'm not saying your wrong as i don't know anything about Mystara just curious.

Comment: @Tom of Vile Darkness, do you can specify where? I was reading the RS main book and only found a suggestion about specialty priests been constructed by GMs basing cleric spheres in immortal spheres (page 107 - chapter 7), but not this specific instructions you present here.

Answer (score 8):

Mystara is a world designed for BECMI D&D, which doesn't have the concept of Spheres. If you're playing AD&D 2nd edition in Mystara, you will have to decide on their Spheres for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer given by Tom of Vile Darkness, the only source of information in 2e to this subject is the "Savage Coast Campaign Book Part 3: The Campaign". In 'The Campaign chapter', section 'Immortals', there is an explanation about Immortal Spheres:

[image: spheres]

The sidebar describing the spheres is as Tom answered:

[image: spheres_and_spells]

Wikipedia states the [Savage Coast Campaign Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Coast_Campaign_Book) as an online product available for free download. There is a link there for a html version, but it is possible to download the [PDF version](http://www.pandius.com/TSR2521-SCS3.pdf) too.

The book presents an [Immortal's description](http://www.pandius.com/sc_camp.html) too.

Comment: I've not downvoted this answer, but a 3,000-word paragraph is uninviting. `:-)`

Comment: I edited the answer with the links to be more inviting. THE SAVAGE COAST, TSR#2521 is cited in some web sites selling printed versions of it as the first fully online product from TSR. But this info is present in TSR#02504 too, the Red Steel Campaign Book, pages 106-110, but without the spheres suggestions.